# Encrypt root file system linux

Tags: linux, cryptsetup

I need encrypt root file system. I used below command

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sda1
```

But i am getting below error.

```
WARNING!
========
 This will overwrite data on /dev/sda1 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase:
Verify passphrase:
[   94.408069] alg: No test for fips(ansi_cprng) (fips_ansi_cprng)
Cannot format device /dev/md126p2 which is still in use.
Command failed with code 16: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: You need to unmount the root filesystem.  This is probably easiest to do from a live distro.

Comment: You can encrypt a file system in-place.

Answer (score 1):

1)  first write random data to the intended partition for more security.
and thin may take some how a long time.

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1
```

2) Make sure that the aes, dm-mod and dm-crypt modules have been loaded into the kernel.

3)

```
# umount /dev/sdb1
```

4) Create a random 256-bit encryption key and store it at /etc/root-key

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/root-key bs=1c count=32
```

5) Create a dm-crypt device, encrypted using the key you just generated

```
# cryptsetup -d /etc/root-key create root /dev/sdb1
```

6)Create an ext3 filesystem on /dev/mapper/root

```
# mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/root
```

7) Mount the new file system

```
# mkdir /mnt/encroot
# mount /dev/mapper/root /mnt/encroot
```

8)

```
# cp -ax / /mnt/encroot
```

9)

```
root /dev/sdb1 /etc/root-key cipher=aes
```

I used the following link as source,
for more explanation read here  [here](https://linoxide.com/file-system/how-to-encrypted-root-partition-filesystem/) also.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is the root partition, I don't think you can unmount it and still use the system.  // You may also want to suggest unmounting it before overwriting with random data.  Linux doesn't seem to be very happy with filesystems suddenly becoming corrupt. :)

Comment: please read the  link i mentioned.

Comment: Unless you are Bobbin Zachariah, you should properly attribute him as the original author.